# force the browser to use HTTPS while login in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.5

In my Grails project i'm using **spring core plugin**  , i want to force the browser to use HTTPS while login , i found this setting :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
```

but when i put it in the Config file,but when i try to access an action that needs to be logged in first rather directing my to the login page using HTTPS it shows me

> This page can't be displayed

as shown in the image attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O91Re.jpg)  anything i'm missing ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two settings with the Grails spring security plugin to use here. the secure channel definition below says that all URLs for the application must use HTTPS and thus will automatically redirect to HTTPS. You can change this definition to suit your needs.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
 '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

Comment: i did the below configurations but still getting the same  **This page can't be displayed**    `grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
 '/login/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
 ]`

Comment: i found http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-configure-ssl-on-tomcat-server-and-run-grailsjava-application-on-https/ , do i need to do these steps too ?